# Deep Linking in IOS with React ( non-native )

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

There are various resources on deep linking with **react native**. However, I have a react app inside an IOS app and I'm not using React Native. How can I get a deep linking to work in that situation?

I have tried something like this:

```
import React                                                                    from 'react';
import ReactDOM                                                                 from 'react-dom';
import App                                                                      from './App';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch }                                         from 'react-router-dom'
import Login                                                                    from './Components/Login'
import iosDeepLink                                                              from './Components/iosDeepLink'

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/apple-app-site-association" component={iosDeepLink}/>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Where Browser Router redirects association URL to component iosDeepLink:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class DeepLink extends Component {
  render() {
    return '{"applinks":{"apps":[]"details":[{"appID": "MYTEAMCODE.MYCOMP.MYAPP","paths":["*"]}]}}';
  }
}
```

not working. I guess it's because there are the other divs and structures that react produces to get to that scene, and it's not just plain text of the association file.

I used [this](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) website to verify, and I got these two errors:

> 1. Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.
> 2. JSON test did not run. Your file should contain valid JSON.

Comment: Your json is invalid, there should be a comma after `"apps": [],` and before `"details": [{`

Comment: right, fixed. errors still persist